# Remove elements from Soundcloud "The Visual embedded player"

Tags: embed, soundcloud

When embedding in a website, is it possible to remove any of the following overlayed elements in "The visual embedded player" from Souncldoud:

- The uploader name
- Playlist title
- The track counter
- The soundcloud logo

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible (as Souncldoud answered ticket on Feb 3rd 2020)